# How to use a variable or name instead of path of the file in a command in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, path, command

I have a shell script `sample.sh`. Inside the shell script, there are many commands, it looks like this for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

command 1 ......

command 2 ......

command 3 ......

txt1="/users/doc/folder1/sam.txt"
txt2="/users/doc/folder2/pam.txt"
txt3="/users/doc/folder3/ram.txt"

echo "run done"
```

First I gave a run with this script like `sh sample.sh`. After running this shell script I want to run a command in which I wanted to give `txt3` which was the name I'm using instead of the path for the file `ram.txt`

The command looks like this for eg:

```
convert -i txt3 > sim.tsv
```

This gave me an error. `Error: The requested txt file (txt3) could not be opened. Exiting!`

May I know how this works without giving the path to the file in the command?

Comment: Your description isn't very clear (at least not to me), but I see two problems. 1) you would need to `source` the script, not run it, and `export` your variables to have them persist after the script finished. 2) you have to refer to the variable as `$txt3`

Comment: Could you please explain clearly how to resolve that 1st problem you mentioned

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-vs-sourcing-it

Comment: I did `source sample.sh` not sure what to do after. I checked the link you posted, but no idea. could you please give me an example.

Comment: **sigh** .. after sourcing it (I assume you added `export` statements in front of you variable definitions?) ... what does `echo $txt3` say?

Comment: oh yes. after `source sample.sh`, I gave `echo $txt3` and then ran the command and it worked. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to source the script, not run it, and `export` your variables to have them persist after the script finished.

You have to refer to the variable as `$txt3` after the sourcing.